# Define own class options relating to counter

Tags: class-options

I created a class file named `class.cls` as follows:

```
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\ProvidesClass{class}
\LoadClass{report}


\RequirePackage{indentfirst}

\DeclareOption{withinchap}{%
    \newcounter{exercounter}[chapter]%
    \setcounter{exercounter}{0}}

\DeclareOption{withinsec}{%
    \newcounter{exercounter}[section]%
    \setcounter{exercounter}{0}}

\DeclareOption*{\PassOptionsToClass{\CurrentOption}{report}}
\ExecuteOptions{withinchap}
\ProcessOptions\relax


\newenvironment{exercise}%
    {\stepcounter{exercounter}\par\textbf{\theexercounter.}}%
    {\ignorespacesafterend}
```

What I want to achieve is to settle a pair of class options `withinchap`(default) and `withinsec`. If using `withinchap`(default) option, the exercise counter `exercounter` is reset to zero when a new chapter starts. If using `withinsec` option, the exercise counter `exercounter` is reset to zero when a new section starts. But when I use `withinsec` option in the `test.tex` file as follows:

```
\documentclass[withinsec]{class}
\usepackage{showframe}
\begin{document}

\chapter{AAAAA}
\section{aaaaa}

\begin{exercise}
This is an exercise.
\end{exercise}

\begin{exercise}
    This is another exercise.
\end{exercise}

\begin{exercise}
    This is the third exercise.
\end{exercise}


\section{bbbbb}

\begin{exercise}
    This is the fourth exercise in chapter one.
\end{exercise}

\begin{exercise}
    This is the fifth exerecise in chapter one.
\end{exercise}


\end{document}
```

After running `pdflatex test` in windows terminal, I got an error message

```
! LaTeX Error: Command \c@exercounter already defined.
               Or name \end... illegal, see p.192 of the manual.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...

l.18 \ProcessOptions\relax

?
! Emergency stop.
 ...

l.18 \ProcessOptions\relax

!  ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!
Transcript written on test.log.

Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...

l.18 \ProcessOptions\relax

?
```

I  want to  know  the  reason of the error.

Comment: By the time the non-default option, i.e., `withinsec`, gets processed, the default option, i.e., `withinchap`, has already been processed, and the counter named `exercounter` has been set up. That is why `\newcounter{exercounter}[section]` generates an error message. What you need, then, is `\renewcounter{exercounter}[section]`. That, or go with [@egreg's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/632018/5001) and use the `\counterwithin` approach.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You *are* doing `\newcounter{exercounter}` multiple times. You can use `\counterwithin` instead.

```
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\ProvidesClass{class}
\LoadClass{report}

\RequirePackage{indentfirst}

\newcounter{exercounter}

\DeclareOption{withinchap}{\counterwithin{exercounter}{chapter}}
\DeclareOption{withinsec}{\counterwithin{exercounter}{section}}
%\DeclareOption*{\PassOptionsToClass{\CurrentOption}{report}}

\ExecuteOptions{withinchap}

\ProcessOptions\relax

\newenvironment{exercise}%
    {\stepcounter{exercounter}\par\textbf{\theexercounter.}}%
    {\ignorespacesafterend}
```

#### Output with the `withinchap` option

[image]

#### Output with the `withinsec` option

[image]

Note that the commented line in the class code does nothing, because the class `report` has already been loaded.

In order to pass options to it, you need to delay the code.

```
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\ProvidesClass{class}

\newcounter{exercounter}

\DeclareOption{withinchap}{\def\exercounter@within{chapter}}
\DeclareOption{withinsec}{\def\exercounter@within{section}}
\DeclareOption*{\PassOptionsToClass{\CurrentOption}{report}}

\ExecuteOptions{withinchap}
\ProcessOptions\relax

\LoadClass{report} % should go after processing options

\RequirePackage{indentfirst}

\newcounter{exercounter}
\counterwithin{exercounter}{\exercounter@within}

\newenvironment{exercise}%
    {\stepcounter{exercounter}\par\textbf{\theexercounter.}}%
    {\ignorespacesafterend}
```

If you just want the exercise number, use `\counterwithin*`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer!